# Recommend good lightweight Task Managment applications for PC

Tags: task-management

Can anyone recommend a good task management application for PC?  I used to use Palm Desktop and loved it but now I use a Black Berry and Outlook at work, however I find Outlook's task functionality fairly painful to use.  Going back to Palm Desktop could work but I really just need something that does tasks management very well and is not too heavyweight.

On my Mac at home I've been looking at [OmniFocus](http://www.omnigroup.com/applications/omnifocus/) which seems fairly decent but it is a Mac only application and I really need something for the PC I use at work.

Comment: this is only borderline programming related really, but personally I do use task management apps to keep track of next steps in programming projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually started using [Evernote](http://www.evernote.com/) and a [Moleskin Journal](http://www.moleskine.com/catalogue/diariesplanners/18_months/18_months__weekly_notebook__black_hard_cover__large.php) for tracking what I work on from day to day.  Although Evernote is a note taking application it is general enough and has tags which seems enough for general task management.

Answer (score 1):

Google Calendar supports tasks (new feature, very bare bones), or you can use the [RememberTheMilk](http://blog.rememberthemilk.com/2007/12/rtm-gmail-task-management-goodness.html) site/gmail add-on.  It's has all the basic features you could ever want and it's simple to use.  If you use an iPhone or the gPhone you can access the website in a 1st class experience from both your desktop and your pocket.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simple and intuitive tree based task list.
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/applications/todolist2.aspx Comes free with source code and many plug-ins

Answer (score 0):

I quite like Life Balance from Llamagraphics. I used to use it on my palm and then treo.

But it also works on Mac and PC (and IPhone). I don't think there is a blackberry version.

It can be used as a basic todo list, but it also has some nice outlining features and a nice way of setting priorities. The IPhone version is still a bit clunky compared to the Palm version, but it's usable. All the versions can synch with each other and on the Mac it has some synch capability with iCal.